# Typescript: type assist for function argument

Tags: typescript, types, type-hinting

I've written a little library and now I'm trying to add type support for it through creating custom d.ts files.

To give an example (my library is called `layerCompose`):

```
const C = layerCompose(
  {
     _($) { /* function body */ },
     execute($) { /* function body */ }
  }
)
const c = C()
c._()
```

You will notice that both `_` and `execute` function take a parameter `$`.
This parameter (in our example) is an object with `_` and `execute` properties (similar to `this` within a class)

So, I'd like to add type support to this `$` parameter. Through experimenting I found that having this definition inside my d.ts file gives type support within the `_` function.

```
export function layerCompose<
  T extends [
    A extends {} 
      ? {
        _($: {test: () => void})
      } 
      : never
  ]
  , A
>(...layers: T): lcConstructor<Spread<T>>
```

In other words Webstorm can see that `$` parameter in `_` function has type `{test: () => void}`

Obviously, that's not what I'm looking for. However, changing the signature to (what seems proper to me)

```
export function layerCompose<
  T extends [
    A extends {} 
      ? { 
        [K in keyof A]: ($: {test: () => void}) => any 
      } 
      : never
  ]
  , A
>(...layers: T): lcConstructor<Spread<T>>
```

and Webstorm looses the ability to tell that `$` is an object with properties `_` and `execute`.

---

EDIT: [Included an example on typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghiCAnAPAZQgGwGYD4oC8UA3gNoDSAXAM7BICWAdgOYC6lUAFACQcY4BKQvgBuAe3oATAL4AoWdgCujAMbB6YxlEwJkAYTEBbMGOoROAOis7ESah3i2UcRiFylWA2QHoAVFGAAC2gkCGBFJC1QSCh6aihDOOomZliowLioCAAPOGNMaABaQtjgBMVaLNy1TBAoSQhqFQYAI2hqQLgYsWwoblkWuDNJKE0oAHdOsoADG2Rqaag4UKgwIeG0qF9vWRJdqAOCst4SCho6FPYoADFlNQ1GaUISOX2D728oFSMWphSlzCYALBbS6OxpYBiJZQZIsAqjFoAKwgajeoNs1As2DESAAonAVIFOECCPhiGiDgcAPJIlHACwAawgIGoxIEWJx%20MJnAZwj2lIFgo%20XwiSBA-yC0H6gplfVIDNYz04QlJ2nlrB4XllUGkWspuvkAtC4UifVkr2%20jEq32MpggIyIcyQBltZk4aPJ2oA%20pr%20drKdwLDkUYpgOY9TK5ALpAAaQ2Uz2y4MqUPmbhCRP%20r6aahiAoWTBiZicADkuOyIfULBLEcFUf1si8shtJmGFh9AiAA). It's missing the return type (non-trivial to set that up quickly), but otherwise gives an insight into what `layerCompose` approximately does.

---

EDIT 2:

Playing around further, having simplified to 1 parameter scenario, this works:

```
export function layerCompose<L1>(l1: {_: ($: {test: () => void}) => void} & L1): void
```

yet this does not:

```
export function layerCompose<L1>(l1: {[K in keyof L1]: ($: {test: () => void}) => void} & L1): void
```

Comment: How is `A` being resolved and why is it unused in the function signature? You should write a fully reproducible example of your problem. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play would be welcome

Comment: The examples you've provided for typing `layerCompose` always results in `T = never`. Are you sure they are being used? Webstorm might not be recognizing your declaration files correctly.

Comment: @GuerricP example added.

Comment: @Olian04 I've been fairly diligent at making sure that updates to my d.ts files are propagated. I can see when Webstorm picks up the signatures and when it fails as I experiment.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
export function layerCompose(...layers: Layer[]): lcConstructor<Spread<T>>;
```

Since you haven't defined neither `lcConstructor` or `Spread` I can't make any real guesses as to what the return type of `layerCompose` is supposed to be. So for the purpose of this answer those types have been replaced with the identity type.

```
// See playground below
type ComposedLayer = {
  _(): void;
  execute(): void;
}
type Layer = {
  _(v: Layer): void;
  execute(v: Layer): void;
}

/* dummy type */ type lcConstructor<T> = ComposedLayer;
/* dummy type */ type Spread<T> = T;

declare function layerCompose(...layers: Layer[]): lcConstructor<Spread<Layer>>;

const C = layerCompose(
  {
     _($) {},
     execute($) {
       $._({
         _($) {},
         execute($) {}
       })
     }
  }
);

C._();
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzHAzhAJgGQIYggJygF4oBvAKCigH0AKASgC4oA3OAS3QG5KoIAPCAGMArsAgNmbTjwC+5UJCg48hEhSp0WzFQSasO3XgOFiJ25bj1TDc8uQD0AKijoRCBCCiLoTh9-BoABsheAA7FGB8ESFgOHwAHgAVAD5iWERkNCwrfB5nV3dPAKU-EugAZTB8CGx0ZLSSJJ5ydGEg7BqoADMRMNj2ODCoDtV4JFQJADoZ0YIUHVyAbQBdfRDwyOjY+ISqmrqE3XwUlJahIcjYdLn8cayJXg0qTVoAEnoyWQAaXheTUTid6fZ4vKhvKZ0UFg14fL6-GFggFmYFfP5g2T0dFQeRUeT0FowSEMLhAA)

Comment: Take a look at the playground example that I provided. The trouble is that I don't know the shape of `Layer` ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

According personal experiences, find something as generic type first, to avoid circular dependencies. Please check following definitions.

```
type Layer<K extends string> = Partial<Record<K, ($: Record<K, Function>) => void>>

function layerCompose<K extends string>(...layers: Layer<K>[]): Record<K, Function>
  // ignore how do you implement to match types
  return {} as Record<K, Function>
}
```